# Make use of the default buttons in the Android sdk

Tags: android

I would like to make a `button`, a simple button, having the default `Search icon` that is used in Android. 
However, **I do not want to make my own xml file** and put the images in the Drawable folder, because i know **they already exist in the Android sdk**.

- So why not making use of them?

I tried to make something like this:

`android:background="@android:drawable/...."` but there in this directory it seems that all the files are png file not xml file able to interact with the user (on button pressed, etc..)

I hope an expert can help solving this problem.

Comment: Post the code you have so we can help.

Comment: Why you can't just use `ImageButton`, and set the `android:src="<path_to_search_icon>"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an xml file for the button to work. The png files in the drawables are just for the image. You can create a button programmatically or in the xml but you still have to create it somewhere because the `Button` instance is what is used for the `onClick()` and not necessarily the xml. Either way you must have an xml file for your `Layout` to use in `setContentView()` so you can put a `Button` in that layout file or create it in your Java code but either way, you have to create a `Button`

[XML](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
              android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Hello, I am a TextView" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello, I am a Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

in this `Button` you can set the background or use an `ImageButton` instead and set `android:src="@drawable/..."

Then in your code you still have to get the button instance

Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button)

after you have called your layout like

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_file);
```

If you use an `ImageButton` just replace `Button` with `ImageButton` which is what it sounds like you want. Hope this helps it make a little more sense for you

Comment: IT seems nobody understood what i actually mean. For example, if i use the ImageButton and set this     android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" then whenever i click on it, it doesn't interact, so i need to create an xml file to work with the state pressed, etc.. is there any other solution that android already knows?

Comment: It worked as you suggested by the way, i tried the ImageButton! This is what i wanted. Thank you!

Comment: I thought that it would. I'm glad that I could help but if you don't understand why then feel free to ask and maybe I can help make sense :)